# Most pythonic way to extend a potentially incomplete list

Tags: python

What I'm looking for is the best way to say, 'If this list is too short, lengthen it to 9 elements and add 'Choice 4', 'Choice 5', etc, as the additional elements. Also, replace any 'None' elements with 'Choice x'.' It is ok to replace "" and 0 too.

An example transformation would be

```
['a','b',None,'c']
```

to

```
['a','b','Choice 3','c','Choice 5','Choice 6','Choice 7','Choice 8','Choice 9']
```

My initial code abused try/except and had an off-by-one error I didn't notice; thanks to joeforker and everyone who pointed it out. Based on the comments I tried two short solutions that test equally well:

```
def extendChoices(cList):
  for i in range(0,9):
    try:
      if cList[i] is None:
        cList[i] = "Choice %d"%(i+1)
    except IndexError:
      cList.append("Choice %d"%(i+1)
```

and

```
def extendChoices(cList):
  # Fill in any blank entries
  for i, v in enumerate(cList):
    cList[i] = v or "Choice %s" % (i+1)

  # Extend the list to 9 choices  
  for j in range(len(cList)+1, 10):
    cList.append("Choice %s" % (j))
```

I think #2 wins as being more pythonic, so it's the one I'll use. It's easy to understand and uses common constructs. Splitting the steps is logical and would make it easier for someone to understand at a glance.

Comment: When you answer this, don't make the mistake of numbering from Choice 0!

Comment: If a choice was the empty string "" or 0 would you want to show it to the user, or would you want to treat it the same way as None?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike `zip`, Python's `map` automatically extends shorter sequences with `None`.

```
map(lambda a, b: b if a is None else a,
    choicesTxt,
    ['Choice %i' % n for n in range(1, 10)])
```

You could simplify the lambda to

```
map(lambda a, b: a or b,
    choicesTxt,
    ['Choice %i' % n for n in range(1, 10)])
```

if it's okay to treat other false-like objects in `choicesTxt` the same as `None`.

Answer (score 7):

My initial reaction was to split the list extension and "filling in the blanks" into separate parts as so:

```
for i, v in enumerate(my_list):
    my_list[i] = v or "Choice %s" % (i+1)

for j in range(len(my_list)+1, 10):
    my_list.append("Choice %s" % (j))

# maybe this is nicer for the extension?
while len(my_list) < 10:
    my_list.append("Choice %s" % (len(my_list)+1))
```

If you do stick with the `try...except` approach, do catch a specific exception as [Douglas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516039/most-pythonic-way-to-extend-a-potentially-incomplete-list/516070#516070) shows. Otherwise, you'll catch **everything**: `KeyboardInterrupts`, `RuntimeErrors`, `SyntaxErrors`, ... . You do not want to do that.

**EDIT:** fixed 1-indexed list error - thanks [DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51025/dns)!

**EDIT:** added alternative list extension

Comment: The second loop should start at len(my_list) + 1; otherwise, the first number will overlap.  For example, if my_list is ["Choice 1"], the second loop is range(1, 10), which will append "Choice 1" again, and result in a list of 10 items, not 9.

Answer (score 3):

I think I'd do something pretty much like that, but with a few tidy ups:

```
for i in range(0,10):
  try:
    if choicesTxt[i] is None:
      choicesTxt[i] = "Choice %d"%i
  except IndexError:
    choicesTxt.append("Choice %d"%i)
```

Of which the only important two are to only catch `IndexError` rather than any exception, and to index from 0.

And the only real problem with the original would be if `choicesTxt` is empty, when the choices added will be off by one.

Answer (score 3):

You could use map (dictionary) instead of list:

```
choices_map = {1:'Choice 1', 2:'Choice 2', 3:'Choice 12'}
for key in xrange(1, 10):
    choices_map.setdefault(key, 'Choice %d'%key)
```

Then you have map filled with your data.
If you want a list instead you can do:

```
choices = choices_map.values()
choices.sort() #if you want your list to be sorted
#In Python 2.5 and newer you can do:
choices = [choices_map[k] for k in sorted(choices_map)]
```

Comment: The example transformation preserves the original ordering, sorting values() would lose that. Instead, choices = [choices_map[k] for k in sorted(choices_map.keys())]

Comment: Assuming, that keys in choices_map reflect the order of original list. But you're right, I'll update my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should treat resizing the array as a separate step.  To do so, in the case the array is too short, call `choicesTxt=choicesTxt+[None]*(10-len(choicesTxt))`.
The `None` choice reasignment can be done using list comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest and most pythonic for me is:

```
repl = lambda i: "Choice %d" % (i + 1) # DRY
print ([(x or repl(i)) for i, x in enumerate(aList)]
     + [repl(i) for i in xrange(len(aList), 9)])
```

Answer (score 1):

What about that (seems to be a dict -- not a list -- when it's *incomplete*)

```
a = {1:'a', 2:None, 5:'e'} #test data
[a[x] if x in a and a[x] is not None else 'Choice %d'%x for x in xrange(1,10)]
```

Edit once more: If it's really a list (not a dict):

```
b=['a',None,'b']
[b[x] if len(b)>x and b[x] is not None else 'Choice %d'%x for x in xrange(10)]
```

needs Python 2.5 I think (because of the ternary operator)?

(Thanks to joeforker fixed that it uses keys 1 to 10 and not 0 to 10 anymore; thanks to SilentGhost: in is more pythonic than has_key() or len())

Comment: .has_key() is not pythonic at all

Comment: x in b doesn't make no sense ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind replacing anything that evaluates to False with "Choice %d", then `result` works for Python 2.4.

If you do mind and have Python 2.5 and above then use `result2_5_plus` with the power of ternary `if`.

If you don't like or can't use ternary if, then take advantage of the fact that `True == 1` and `False == 0`, using the result of `x is None` to index a list.

```
x = ["Blue", None, 0, "", "No, Yelloooow!"]
y = [None]*9

result = [(t or "Choice %d" % (i+1))\ 
        for i, t in enumerate(x + y[len(x):])]

result2_5_plus = [(t if t is not None else "Choice %d" % (i+1))\ 
        for i, t in enumerate(x + y[len(x):])]

result_no_ternary_if = [[t, "Choice %d" % (i+1)][t is None]\
    for i, t in enumerate(x + y[len(x):])]

['Blue', 'Choice 2', 'Choice 3', 'Choice 4', 'No, Yelloooow!', 'Choice 6', 'Choice 7', 'Choice 8', 'Choice 9']
['Blue', 'Choice 2', 0, '', 'No, Yelloooow!', 'Choice 6', 'Choice 7', 'Choice 8', 'Choice 9']
```

Comment: but then '', 0 and [] get replaced by "Choice n". Thats not wanted I think

Comment: He might want it, the empty string is not a very good choice to show to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear about why you're using range(1, 10); since you're using choicesTxt[i], that ends up skipping the None check for the first element in your list.

Also, there are obviously easier ways to do this if you're creating a new list, but you're asking specifically to add to an existing list.

I don't think this is really cleaner or faster, but it's a different idea for you to think about.

```
for i, v in enumerate(choicesTxt):
    choicesTxt[i] = v or "Choice " + str(i + 1)

choicesTxt.extend([ "Choice " + str(i) for i in range(len(choicesTxt) + 1, 10) ])
```

Comment: You mean choicesTxt[i] = "Choice " + str(i + 1) if v is None else v?  That would prevent False or "" from triggering it, but he seems to be filling a list with non-False values, so this may be closer to what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
for i, c in enumerate(choices):
    if c is None:
        choices[i] = 'Choice X'

choices += ['Choice %d' % (i+1) for i in range(len(choices), 10)]
```

which only replaces actual `None` values (not anything that evaluates as false), and extends the list in a separated step which I think is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I find that when list comprehensions get long it's better to just use a standard for loop.
Nearly the same as others but anyway:

```
>>> in_list = ["a","b",None,"c"]
>>> full_list = in_list + ([None] * (10 - len(in_list)))
>>> for idx, value in enumerate(full_list):
...     if value == None:
...             full_list[idx] = 'Choice %d' % (idx + 1)
...
>>> full_list
['a', 'b', 'Choice 3', 'c', 'Choice 5', 'Choice 6', 'Choice 7', 'Choice 8', 'Choice 9', 'Choice 10']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
choices[:] = ([{False: x, True: "Choice %d" % (i + 1)}[x is None] for i, x in enumerate(choices)] +
  ["Choice %d" % (i + 1) for i in xrange(len(choices), 9)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go simpler with a list comprehension:

```
extendedChoices = choices + ([None] * (10 - len(choices)))
newChoices = ["Choice %d" % (i+1) if x is None else x
    for i, x in enumerate(extendedChoices)]
```

This appends `None` to your choices list until it has at least 10 items, enumerates through the result, and inserts "Choice X" if the Xth element is missing.

Comment: In general, whenever I find myself writing a for loop with one line of code in it, I think about what it would look like as a list comprehension.

Comment: that's true, but I liked algorithm: refill with Nones and replace them afterwards - more dry

Answer (score 1):

```
def choice_n(index):
  return "Choice %d" % (index + 1)

def add_choices(lst, length, default=choice_n):
  """
  >>> add_choices(['a', 'b', None, 'c'], 9)
  ['a', 'b', 'Choice 3', 'c', 'Choice 5', 'Choice 6', 'Choice 7', 'Choice 8', 'Choice 9']
  """

  for i, v in enumerate(lst):
    if v is None:
      lst[i] = default(i)

  for i in range(len(lst), length):
    lst.append(default(i))

  return lst

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import doctest
  doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well in one line:

`[a or 'Choice %d' % i for a,i in map(None,["a","b",None,"c"],range(10))]`

Though that will replace anything that evaluates to False (e.g. None, '', 0 etc) with "Choice n".  Best to replace the `"a or 'Choice %d' % i"` with a function if yuo don't want that.

The key thing is that `map` with an argument of None can be used to extend the list to the length needed with None in the required places.

A tidier (more pythonic) version would be:

`def extend_choices(lst,length):
    def replace_empty(value,index):
        if value is None:
            return 'Choice %d' % index
        return value
    return [replace_empty(value,index) for value,index in map(None,lst,range(length))]`

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using xrange instead of range.  The xrange function generates the numbers as needed.  Range generates them in advance.  For small sets it doesn't make much difference, but for large ranges the savings can be huge.

Comment: In Python 3.0 we don't have to worry about this anymore because range returns an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> in_list = ["a","b",None,"c"]
>>> new = ['choice ' + str(i + 1) if j is None else j for i, j in enumerate(in_list)]
>>> new.extend(('choice ' +str(i + 1) for i in range(len(new), 9)))
>>> new
['a', 'b', 'choice 3', 'c', 'choice 5', 'choice 6', 'choice 7', 'choice 8', 'choice 9']
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents...

```
def extendchoices(clist):
    clist.extend( [None]*(9-len(clist)) )
    for i in xrange(9):
        if clist[i] is None: clist[i] = "Choice %d"%(i+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to replace any false value, eg '' or 0

```
>>> mylist = ['a','b',None,'c']
>>> map(lambda a,b:a or "Choice %s"%b, mylist, range(1,10))
['a', 'b', 'Choice 3', 'c', 'Choice 5', 'Choice 6', 'Choice 7', 'Choice 8', 'Choice 9']
```

If you really can only replace for None

```
>>> map(lambda a,b:"Choice %s"%b if a is None else a, mylist, range(1,10))
['a', 'b', 'Choice 3', 'c', 'Choice 5', 'Choice 6', 'Choice 7', 'Choice 8', 'Choice 9']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> my_list=['a','b',None,'c']
>>> map (lambda x,y:x or 'Choice {}'.format(y+1),my_list,range(9))
['a', 'b', 'Choice 3', 'c', 'Choice 5', 'Choice 6', 'Choice 7', 'Choice 8', 'Choice 9']
```